# Path payment is taking only 4 hops BUT stellar is mentioning upto 6 hops

Tags: stellar-core, horizon, path-payment, paths

Let assets are A,B,C,D,E,F

I have created few orders like
    A->B
    B->C
    C->D
    D->E
    E->F

Now, i have created an order where user1 is selling "F" to a destination user2 and the receiving Asset is "A"

After calling finding path methods it is showing me below output (Where the first letter of each asset represent the Asset i have mentioned above means "AXY" is "A").

```
    {
    "source_asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
    "source_asset_code": "EXY",
    "source_asset_issuer": "GA24WKNRNMEMKK3PYE4GPFCNFWRP75MUYDBYJEGRMEZE3EKCSRBEYSBK",
    "source_amount": "96.0000000",
    "destination_asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
    "destination_asset_code": "AXY",
    "destination_asset_issuer": "GBQF24JXLPXRWGTCGHWMXECOEE3VFYXJUWFRHIVNEF7GE6TQK2H3FXE4",
    "destination_amount": "1.0000000",
    "path": [
      {
        "asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
        "asset_code": "DXY",
        "asset_issuer": "GCJ3ODETXMRTNCRD6BHHYUFLBVIQJHZVBYBVES6QDNRMJAF3ACZC47B6"
      },
      {
        "asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
        "asset_code": "CLM",
        "asset_issuer": "GA5ZB6DSHSOBNEYSCXH3ULEIYT5V2WOJRCWQE4ANZ56B6BVZF6XSSIQX"
      },
      {
        "asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
        "asset_code": "BCZ",
        "asset_issuer": "GC5DKZTNXPMLRYSBB7QRH2QWTMEP56USAXJHA5LMTYOTXJO6CDVIHQRD"
      }
    ]
  }
```

So, total 4 hops it is showing, BUT stellar mention in their document that upto 6 hops it can accept. Already mentioned that my order exist from "E" to "F" also.
My horizon version is v0.23.0. What could be the possible reason?

Answer (score 1):

Horizon always returns the **optimal** path. The `E->F` part is redundant in this particular case as you requested payment path from `E` to `A`. And that's what we clearly see here: `EXY->DXY->CLM->BCZ->AXY`.

Comment: This is the output of "server.paths(source_account, destination_account, destination_asset, destination_amount)" which gives all possibilities. This is the last excerpt from the output having maximum hops.  In the above case, user 1st wants to send "F"(source_asset_code) to the user 2nd where receiving asset is "A"(destination_asset_code). So again, why this is not working?